# Python: I have a list of date.I want to calculate the number of days till current date

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to calculate the number of days till today from this list.

```
dateslist = [datetime.date(2014, 11, 5), datetime.date(2014, 11, 5), datetime.date(2014, 11, 17), datetime.date(2014, 11, 5)]
```

Edit: This question was marked duplicate. But I wanted to calculate the number of days, not the time.
I was able to solve this one. Here is the code for reference.

```
no_of_days = []
for a in dateslist:
    no_of_days.append((datetime.date(2019,1,12) - a).days)
```

Comment: Hi Rishab, can you add more detail around what you the expected output should look like? Thanks

Comment: Not quite a duplicate since Rishab is asking for days, not just a datetime difference.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a list of dates by the following:

```
import datetime as dt

daysTillToday = [(dt.datetime.now() - r).days for r in dateslist]
```